# How to check if a sales rules coupon is allowed

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, quote, coupon, coupon-codes

I'm trying to know how can I check if a sales rules coupon is allowed for a quote in magento 1.9.

Here the scenario :

I have a few active rules in my shop and I would like to check if one of them is allow when a customer going to add a product in the cart.

Here my code :

```
 public function detectQuoteAction(){

    //Quote is equivalent to the cart information
    $oQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $sDateNow = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');

    $oCollectionRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_rss', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', array('lteq' => $sDateNow))
        ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', array('gteq' => $sDateNow));

    foreach ($oCollectionRule as $rule)
    {
        if (!$rule->getCode()) {
            continue;
        }

        if rule valid 
          set coupon code
    }
```

Someone can help me about this check ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The sales rules heavily depend on the customer group and address.
The validation is done in `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php` by the `protected function _canProcessRule($rule, $address)`.

Since `_canProcessRule` is a protected method, you can't use it directly, but you can extend `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php` and add your own logic to validate the rules.

An untested example might be something like that:

```php
class Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Model_Validator extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator
{

    public function detectQuoteAction()
    {

        //Quote is equivalent to the cart information
        $oQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $sDateNow = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');

        $address = $oQuote->getShippingAddress();

        $oCollectionRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_rss', 1)
            ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', ['lteq' => $sDateNow])
            ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', ['gteq' => $sDateNow]);

        foreach ($oCollectionRule as $rule) {
            if (!$rule->getCode()) {
                continue;
            }

            if($this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
                $oQuote->setCouponCode($rule->getCode())->save()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your response but this method allow rule who don't respect the condition.